# Symfony2 jquery not working in twig

Tags: jquery, symfony-2.8

i'm at the moment working on a new website with symfony2, i'm still a noob and i just can't use jquery :

I added the file jquery-3.2.1.min.js in my folder web/bundles/app/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js and so I wrote in my index.html.twig :

```
 <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"
 type="text/javascript">


    var button = document.getElementById('divertir'); 

button.onclick = function() {

   $('#video').show();

    $(this).hide();
    $('#divertir').removeClass('hcbutton');
    };
</script>
```

But it doesn't work and I really don't understand why ... please help me

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found the solution ... just put

```
 <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in header and the following

```
 <script>
```

will access to jquery ...